# Test code not there in any file after doing npm run build

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a existing pretty old react project (2014 ?).
I need to insert a div (a footer actually) after the root. (I need to insert it *after* root)

In index.html I have :

```
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="react-footer"></div>
```

And in dev/index.html I have the following which calls loadFooter() in init()

```
const setupFooter = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{'border':'1px solid maroon'}}>Footer Content here</div>
  )
}

const loadFooter = () =>
{
  ReactDOM.render( setupFooter() , document.getElementById('react-footer'))  
}
```

Its there when I do `npm run start` on localhost:3000.
But I did `npm run build`, and did `cd build && grep -irl "maroon" *` there are not results.
Why is my build folder not containing the test div code ?

Comment: Production build is always minified.

Comment: So what happened to the maroon string ? How did that get minified and to what ?